# Visual Studio Express 2013 installation error Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-7-x64

I have problem when installing Visual Studio Express 2013 Windows Desktop.
I am using, Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1 64bit and I have Windows up to date.

When i double click "wdexpress_full.exe", it only appear :
[image]

Then atfer 10 - 15 seconds, I got this error appear:
[image]

From the error, it says that the application was crash. But I don't have any clue how to fix. Any help for will be very usefull for me.

Thanks,